# achieving fast performance using polymorphism and functors in c++

Tags: c++, performance, polymorphism, functor

I am currently writing a Maya 2013 plugin in c++ that optimizes the geometry of given mesh for specific constraints. i need to achieve maximum performance. for now i only implemented an hard-coded version of the algorithm for a specific constraint and it's very fast, but i need achieve some king of generic implementation of the algorithm for any given constraint (thus i need some kind of polymorphism).

a pseudo code for the general structure of the algorithm is:

```
(1) do k times:
(2)      for every face fj in the mesh do: 
(3)            some manipulation on the vertices qi incident to the face fj
(4)      for every vertex  vi in the mesh do: 
(5)            some manipulation  on the faces fj incident to the vertex vi
```

the problem is that in my specific implementation there is no function calls for the calculations in steps 3 and 5 in the pseudo code, when i tried calculating those steps with auxiliary functions there was a big reduction on performance.

for a generic implementation i need to make function calls in steps 3 and 5 for every constraint.

i thought of two kinds of solutions:

1. write a generic class for constraints. derive classes for every constraint i need with methods for calculaing steps 3 and 5 in the algorithm.
2. write a general functor (class with only the () operator) and derive from it functors for calculating steps 3 and 5. the reason for this idea is that the call for the () operator in a functor is inlined ([answer about reusable code in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182672/is-template-metaprogramming-faster-than-the-equivalent-c-code)).

**first question**:

> is there any way to reduce the overhead for the function calls?

**second question**:

> is there any way to make the compiler always inline the functions in
>   the two solutions above? from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733737/are-inline-virtual-functions-really-a-non-sense) i know that virtual
>   functions called from pointers to objects can't be inlined.

**third question**:

> is there a more efficient way then the solutions i proposed?

Comment: `operator()` is just a regular member function with a funny name. It has no more or less chance to get inlined than a member function with any other name. In particular, when it's virtual for a good reason, this chance is virtually zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you take look at templates and pass a template function/functor as a parameter.
With *dynamic* polymorphism you almost always have indirect call to function, ie the body of the function isn't known to compiler - hence optimization options are limited.
Templates allow you to do what is called a *static* polymorphism.

see these links for more info:

[Static polymorphism definition and implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557141/static-polymorphism-definition-and-implementation)

[C++ templates for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925177/c-templates-for-performance)

Comment: is it possible to inline static functions inside classes that are using static polymorphism?

Comment: yes.  however keep in mind that inline keyword is merely a hint.  Most of compilers will inline a small function regardless.  your best bet is to check assembly to be sure.

Comment: thank you very much!! i have a few more questions :P      

i need a list of derived classes. how to i keep such a list if i use static polymorphism? because the derived classes take the shape base<derived>.     

is it possible to take a variable number of template parameters?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking but it sounds vaguely like CRTP pattern.  You can have variable number of template parameters in C++11 but a lot of times you can emulate that using default template parameters.

Comment: yes i asked about CRTP pattern. after i read your answer i searched about static polymorphism and found about CRTP in Wikipedia. i think i will use it to optimize performance in my code, thank you for directing me to static polymorphism and CRTP pattern, great c++ tricks!!!!!!

Comment: @DontCareBear np man.  if you want to see some really cool stuff, check out Eigen - my hunch you are in scientific computing and it may be of use to you.

Comment: i use it for my project already :) very very good library!!!! the first time i implemented my algorithm was on matlab and it took half a minute to run. with Eigen and parallel computing (open mp) it was instantaneous (40 milliseconds or something like that maybe much less)!!!